# How can I split a whole MIDI file in multiple parts?

Tags: python, midi, mido

For a project I am working on, I would like to split all of the .mid files of my database in smaller parts, specifically 30 seconds each (so a 1min45s song would end up in 4 parts, respectively 30s, 30s, 30s and 15s long). I tried using mido to do it, but I was unsuccessful, I only seem to be able to process one track at a time instead of taking out the 30 first seconds of each tracks as one separate midi file.
My files all contain multiple instruments tracks. Should I process them after converting them to format 0?

Comment: *I tried using mido to do it, but I was unsuccessful.* Please show us the code you wrote to use `mido` to do it and the stack trace that explained why it failed, or if it didn't fail, a more explicit explanation of what did not work as expected. You are asking you to guess what you did and then suggest how that might have been wrong.

Comment: Converting files to format 0 is the easiest solution.